# Click event is called more than once in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I have following code. In this code first I am adding `input` field and `button` to `#container`. Then I attach click event to the `button.confirm`. When it is clicked on the first time, it invokes `initConfirm` method. Inside `initConfirm`, I changed the text of a button to `Show` and remove the class `confirm` and add class `show` to this button. Then I attach another click event to `button.show` and it invokes `initShow` method upon click. Inside `initShow` method I am just logging a message.

**Problem**

The problem this code is when I click on the `button.confirm` button for the first time, it shows, it changes the text of the button to `show` and changes the class from `confirm` to `show` and attach click event to `button.show`. It also logs out `initConfirm` once. Which is correct. Now when I click on the button with class `show` then again it invokes `initConfirm` method first then invokes `initShow` method. When I click on this button again. Then again it first invokes `initConfirm` first and then `initShow` twice. This continues when I click this method as many times. Below is the screenshot of my console.

[image]

**What I want**

I want this code to work like this. When user clicks on `.confirm` button on the first time then it should invoke `initConfirm` method. When user clicks on `.show` button then it should invoke `initShow` method and after that it should keep invoking `initShow` method once every time I click on `.show` button.

Here is my code

```
(function () {
    $('#container').append('<input type="text"><button class="confirm" type="button">Confirm</button>');

    $('.confirm').on('click', initConfirm);

    function initConfirm() {
        $('.confirm').text('Show');
        $('.confirm').removeClass('confirm').addClass('show');
        $('.show').on('click', initShow);
        console.log('initConfirm');
    }

    function initShow () {
        console.log('initShow');
    }
})();
```

Here is jsfiddle

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cfS2x/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take advantage of delegation:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cfS2x/8/)

```
function initConfirm() {
    $(this).text('Show')
        .toggleClass('confirm show');
    console.log('initConfirm');
}

function initShow() {
    console.log('initShow');
}
$('#container').on('click', '.confirm', initConfirm)
    .on('click', '.show', initShow);
```

Answer (score 0):

`click` event for `.show` is called as many times as `initConfirm()` is called.

Move

```
$('.show').on('click', initShow);
```

out of `initConfirm()`.

Code:

```
$('#container').append('<input type="text"><button class="confirm" type="button">Confirm</button>');

$('.confirm').on('click', initConfirm);
$('.show').on('click', initShow);

function initConfirm() {
    $('.confirm').text('Show');
    $('.confirm').removeClass('confirm').addClass('show');
    console.log('initConfirm');
}

function initShow() {
    console.log('initShow');
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cfS2x/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `initConfirm` was still attached to the button. I have made the required changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/cfS2x/5/